# New to Python: getting NameError in variable

Tags: python

NameError: name 'Brandon' is not defined

I have a simple username/password program in Python 2.7.2 and keep getting this dumb error message.

Here's my code:

```
Username = input ("Please enter your username: ")
if Username == brandon:
    password = input ("Correct! Please enter password: ")

    if password == 42:
            print "Access granted!"

    else:
            print "Wrong Password!"
else:
    print "Wrong username"
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use raw_input instead of input, because input expect that you're entering python code.  More accurately though, your trouble is in `Username == brandon`.  `brandon` would be a variable.  `'brandon'` would be a string for use in comparison.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! I was getting the same thing with raw_input. I didn't want to put brandon in quotes, though, because I thought it would turn into something I didn't want, since I'm only using that for print commands right now.

Comment: @Brandon - glad to help.  Please be sure to accept answers so that you continue to receive high quality answers from other users.

Answer (score 4):

Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

`input` is essentially running `eval(raw_input(...))`. And you don't want to do an `eval` here.

Also, your `password == 42` should probably be `password == "42"`, since `raw_input` gives back a string.

Comment: I get the same thing using raw_input, but I'll check again.

Edit: yep, get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
# raw_input() reads every input as a string
# then it's up to you to process the string
str1 = raw_input("Enter anything:")
print "raw_input =", str1

# input() actually uses raw_input() and then tries to
# convert the input data to a number using eval()
# hence you could enter a math expression
# gives an error if input is not numeric eg. $34.95
x = input("Enter a number:")
print "input =", x
```